# How to print in C

Tags: c

Very much a beginner to C, in fact this is my first tester program.

I can't actually figure out how to print this number out to the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 7;

    printf(addNumbers(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure that in Java I could just replace the `printf` with `System.out` and it would have worked. I tried searching the answer earlier but if you don't know what to search it's hard to find an answer.

Comment: You may find http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ very helpful, see the section on the Standard C Library.

Answer (score 56):

try this:

```
printf("%d", addNumber(a,b))
```

Here's the [documentation for printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Might want to add a newline or `fflush(stdout)`.

Answer (score 28):

The first argument to `printf()` is always a string value, known as a format control string.  This string may be regular text, such as

```
printf("Hello, World\n"); // \n indicates a newline character
```

or

```
char greeting[] = "Hello, World\n";
printf(greeting);
```

This string may also contain one or more *conversion specifiers*; these conversion specifiers indicate that additional arguments have been passed to `printf()`, and they specify how to format those arguments for output.  For example, I can change the above to

```
char greeting[] = "Hello, World";
printf("%s\n", greeting);
```

The "%s" conversion specifier expects a pointer to a 0-terminated string, and formats it as text.

For signed decimal integer output, use either the "%d" or "%i" conversion specifiers, such as

```
printf("%d\n", addNumber(a,b));
```

You can mix regular text with conversion specifiers, like so:

```
printf("The result of addNumber(%d, %d) is %d\n", a, b, addNumber(a,b));
```

Note that the conversion specifiers in the control string indicate the *number* and *types* of additional parameters.  If the number or types of additional arguments passed to `printf()` don't match the conversion specifiers in the format string then the behavior is undefined.  For example:

```
printf("The result of addNumber(%d, %d) is %d\n", addNumber(a,b));
```

will result in anything from garbled output to an outright crash.

There are a number of additional flags for conversion specifiers that control field width, precision, padding, justification, and types.  Check your handy C reference manual for a complete listing.

Comment: I can't in good conscience upvote an answer that suggests printf(<char*>). Haven't we learned to Always explicitly specify the format string yet? I like the rest of the answer, though.

Comment: @AndrewColeson I do not see what you are talking about. This answer uses the format `"Hello, world\n"`, which happens not to contain any substitutions, and others. The format is “Always explicitly specified”.

Comment: @PascalCuoq he's talking about `printf(greeting)` which is harmless in this example, but still makes me (and presumably others) cringe a little.

Comment: @Cubic Before one can learn to run, one must learn to walk. Before learning to use `printf()` securely and, more important, **obviously** securely so that reviewers can focus their attention on real problems, one has to learn that `printf()` takes a pointer to `const char`, any pointer to `const char`. Skipping steps in the process only leads to “programming by superstition”, and there is already far too much of it in the case of C. This answer is the right answer for someone who's passing an integer as first argument of `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a placeholder in c, it is not like java where you can just print the value. So the placeholder of an integer in c is d. Also, I advise you to pick different characters for your function arguments just for better readability as it is recommended for better and safer code. Finally, you can just skip `int sum = a + b;` in the function and have the function `return a+b;`. Therefore, the final code would be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    int num1 = 4;
    int num2 = 7;

    printf("%d",addNumbers(num1,num2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

printf is a fair bit more complicated than that. You have to supply a format string, and then the variables to apply to the format string. If you just supply one variable, C will assume that is the format string and try to print out all the bytes it finds in it until it hits a terminating nul (0x0).

So if you just give it an integer, it will merrily march through memory at the location your integer is stored, dumping whatever garbage is there to the screen, until it happens to come across a byte containing 0.

For a Java programmer, I'd imagine this is a rather rude introduction to C's lack of type checking. Believe me, this is only the tip of the iceberg. This is why, while I applaud your desire to expand your horizons by learning C, I highly suggest you do whatever you can to avoid writing real programs in it.

(This goes for everyone else reading this too.)