# how to this error in C : incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf'

Tags: c

I am new to programming in C and created a simple script as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static float w = 10.00;


int main()
{


    printf(w);

    return 0;

}
```

However, when I tried to run this script the following error occurred:

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf'
```

This is just a simple print statement, and I have no idea why there is an error

Comment: The [`printf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-170) function expects the first argument to be a formatting string. So here, you need `printf("%f", w);`

Comment: Because the first argument to `printf` is the format string, which you have not provided. Did you try reading the documentation for the function at all, or search for any examples on how to use it?

Comment: C isn't like many other languages, where you can pass a variable directly to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used C in a few months, but I should be able to help you out regardless. Unlike languages like Python, in C, it is important to specify what data format you are trying to print. Adding the term `"%f"` to your print statement will tell your compiler that you intend to print out a float value. Here is what the syntax could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static float w = 10.00;
int main()
{
    printf("%f", w);
    return 0;
}
```

For more information on printing values in C, I recommend that you check out out the following resources:

- https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output
- [How to print in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162758/how-to-print-in-c)

As I mentioned above, I have not been programming in C recently. Thus my suggestions may not be 100% optimal. Regardless, they should help you get started on your C journey!

Comment: In fact, `%f` outputs a `double` value. The `float w` is *promoted* to `double` because `printf()` is a **variadic function** (and integer types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`).

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("w");
```

You need to add the parenthesis.